# question R statistics assessing probability of cases

Tags: r

Suppose we are interested in the group of 25 students. What equals  the probability that two or more students are born the same date.
 To assess the probability we take random number  from 001  to 365 and play 25 cases. If there revealed 2 or more numbers equal to each other, then the answer is 'Yes' - (there is a probability).
I would like to conduct such a trial for 1000 times.  First, we calculate the sum of number of "yes"-es for 1000 attempts and divide it on 1000. 
Is it possible to write the program for the above mentioned case in the R statistics and how? 
I want to calculate the same possibility for 2000, 3000, 4000 and 5000 trials.
waiting for your respond

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the probabilities then use the `pbirthday` function in R.

If you want to do this by simulation to learn more about simulations, or the problem itself (either are good goals) then use the `sample` function to choose samples (set replace to TRUE), then use `any` and `duplicated` to see if there are dublicates (or `any` and `table` if you want to look at higher counts), then look at the `replicate` function for how to do the whole process a bunch of times.  The whole simulation can be done in just one line of R code.

Are you sure that nobody was born on Feb. 29th?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few pointers since this looks like homework (my apologies if not).

`sample` will take a vector of numbers and randomly pick out `size` number of elements. You can check if there are any duplicates in your sample using `duplicated`. You can run this in a for loop using the syntax `for (i in 1:number.of.runs) {}`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google search will point you to this [detailed PDF](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~amyf/stat341/birthday.pdf), where it's described step by step.

Cheers.